# Disabled products still visible in configurable product options

Tags: inventory, out-of-stock

Our client prefers not to use Magento's inventory management tools, so when he sells out of an item he prefers to manually disable it. Our problem is that despite disabling the simple product it's still showing up on the front-end of the site on the configurable product page.

If you try to add it to the cart it correctly says the item is unavailable, but we don't want the item to be visible at all… how do we do this?

For both simple and configurable products under Inventory "Manage Stock" is set to "No", and under System -> Config -> Inventory -> Stock options "Display Out of Stock Products" is also set to "No".